# How to create fallback for CDN libraries without using document.write()

Tags: javascript, html, cdn, fallback

I want to include 3rd party libraries, such as jQuery, from CDN. I also want to create a fallback so if the CDN fails, I include my own local copy. I have followed the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257923/how-to-load-local-script-files-as-fallback-in-cases-where-cdn-are-blocked-unavai):

This is how I include jQuery in my page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>');</script>
```

At the same time [Google is saying that](https://web.dev/no-document-write/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=devtools) `document.write()` is unreliable and should not be used:

> Using document.write() can delay the display of page content by tens
> of seconds and is particularly problematic for users on slow
> connections. Chrome therefore blocks the execution of document.write()
> in many cases, meaning you can't rely on it.

Is there any alternative method to create fallback for the CDNs?

Comment: You can append a dynamically created `<script>` element to the DOM. This has the same effect as `document.write`, but a bit better. However, AFAIK, it's not often required to create a fallback for CDNs (reliability is one of their main points)

Comment: I wouldn't create fallbacks for CDNs on my site, but you can use @dcangulo's answer it you want them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using 3p packages like [fallback.js](https://github.com/dolox/fallback/tree/master#getting-started) or [require.js](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn#how-its-set-up) given they are more scalable in case you have multiple fallbacks and they give you faster loading performance.

> Example of fallback.js

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- **The `data-main` attribute tells the library to load `main.js`** -->
    <script async data-main="main" src="fallback.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

MAIN JS FILE

```
cfg({
  "libs": {
    "jQuery": {
      "urls": [
        "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min",
        "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min"
      ]
    },  
  }
});

req(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery("body");
});
```

> Example of require.js

```
requirejs.config({
  enforceDefine: true,
  paths: {
    jquery: [
      'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js',
      //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
      'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'
    ]
  }
});

require(['jquery'], function ($) {});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind loading it asynchronously you can do it like this:

```js
function fallback() {
  var element = document.createElement('script');
  element.type = 'text/javascript';
  element.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'; // or your path to your local script
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

window.jQuery || fallback();

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(window.jQuery);
}, 1000); // Add timeout since script is loaded asynchronously
```

Comment: You could even attach an `onload` event to the script instead of the timeout.

Comment: I tried this solution and it did not work... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67733961/how-to-add-fallback-for-a-failing-cdn) is the problem that I faced and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172589/document-write-vs-appendchild) is the reason